# Negation issue in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a problem writing the kb to add below fact:

No spiders are mammals

```
spider(X):- \+ (mammal(X)).
```

but the when I query `(mammal(X))` it gives error ?

any help in how to write it??

Answer (score 1):

The following two sentences are not the same: "No spiders are mammals." and "Something is a spider if it's not a mammal.".

Your clause:

```
spider(X):- \+ mammal(X).
```

is a representation of the second sentence.

---

Let's say you have this knowledge base:

```
mammal(tiger).
spider(X):- \+ mammal(X).
```

and see some example queries:

```
?- spider(tiger).
false.

?- spider(tarantula).
true.

?- spider(X).
false.
```

The problematic one is the last query, as one would expect to be satisfied with `X` being unified with all known spiders. But, the goal `\+ mammal(X)` when `X` is a free variable is equivalent with "there are no mammals (in your knowledge base)". Second, you have no goal that instantiates `X`. So, you might want to change it to something similar to:

```
spider(X):- animal(X), \+ mammal(X).
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see 2 problems:
the first one is simply a typo: the operator is [(+)/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28%5C%2B%29/1), so it the clause should be written

```
spider(X):- \+ mammal(X).
```

the second problem is more complex, both to understand and solve. Negation in Prolog means *not provable* under the *closed* domain knowledge (see CWA, [Closed World Assumption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-world_assumption)). What is means in this simple context: you *must* pass X already instantiated to the clause